# iptables-like NETMAP with nftables

Tags: linux, linux-networking, nat, nftables

using nftables, I need to NAT an entire subnet to another one for example:

```
10.10.10.1 -> 10.200.0.1
10.10.10.2 -> 10.200.0.2
...
10.10.10.X -> 10.200.0.X
```

nftables docs [here](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Multiple_NATs_using_nftables_maps) shows multiple NATs in one line, but how can I manage that use case if my subnet is /24 or bigger? Do I have to list hundreds of addresses manually?

I've looked documentation and examples but didn't found a solution.

Than you very much in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now you can do it with bitwise operation:

```
ip saddr 10.10.10.0/24 snat to ip saddr & 255.0.0.255 | 0.200.0.0
```

"Proper" support is already in git.

UPDATE: [apparently](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=35a6b10c1bc488ca195e9c641563c29251f725f3) the "proper" syntax is as follows:

```
snat ip prefix to ip saddr map { 10.10.10.0/24 : 10.200.0.0/24 }
```

Comment: Can you update this answer to provide an example of the "proper" syntax?